# Bootstrap css: aligning columns on small screens

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

**EDIT:**
After implementing the accepted answer below, I have the following, which is what I originally had before implementing any push/pull tactics. Thus the problem persists. Any suggestions that could help achieve the desired layout on small screens are welcome.

```
----------------------------
|  Left Sidebar  |         |
------------------  Main   |
|                |         |
|                |         |
|                |         |
|                |         |
|                |         |
-----------------|---------|            
|  Right         |
------------------
```

I have 3 columns in one row in a fluid container (container-fluid). I have been trying to align them correctly on screen size changes all day, but to no avail.

1: right sidebar

2: left sidebar

3: main

What it looks on big screens:

```
------------------------------------------------
|   Left sidebar  |      Main      |  Right Sidebar |
------------------------------------------------
```

What it should look like on smaller screens:

```
----------------------------
|  Left Sidebar  |         |
------------------  Main   |
|  Right Sidebar |         |
----------------------------
```

What it looks like now:

```
-----------------------------
|  Left          |  Main    |
|  Sidebar       ------------
|                |  Right   |
|                | sidebar  |
-----------------------------
```

I have tried different combination of col-sm-push/pull-x and col-xs-push/pull-x, but none of them have produced the desired output. I kept getting the columns overlapped on top of each other on big screens, instead of nicely beneath each other on smaller screens as intended. How can I achieve the right layout on small screens?

Comment: Can you post a bootply or fiddle?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/45k5HIveao

Comment: @user3694391 I would say that is not the set up you are quite looking for in bootstrap. I am working on a bootply now for you.'

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate anything that helps me move forward.

Comment: @user3694391 alright the new problem i think is because of rows, i will have to think about it and i will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem before adding panels. Is adding panels even necessary? (I do not want the border styling it brings along since my elements are independently styled without it)

Comment: @user3694391 i used panels because it is clean and easier to demonstrate with, they are not necessary

Comment: Right. All three of the divs (the left sidebar, main, and the right sidebar) are enclosed in one row. I am clueless about how to achieve the desired layout with or without this structure, and would welcome any suggestions that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/95y8fwDP72). I used containers and panels since they look much cleaner. Read about panels and grid i used [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Read about hiding divs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 hidden-xs">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">left</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">main</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 hidden-xs">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">right</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Preview Large**

[image]

**Preview Small**

[image]

First you make a row that will contain all your columns of equal width (col-md-4) where col indicated column, md indicates when the width will be seen in terms of screen size (Desktops (≥992px)), and the width with the max being 12. Next you do the same for a different size screen (sm ≥768px), and choose the width for the resized panels. For hiding panels and divs at a certain resolution, bootstrap uses `hidden-SCREENSIZE` so we add `hidden-xs` to the left and right panels.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I would not have realized that I had to use panels. For xs screens, I'd only like to show the main div and nothing else on the sides. I tried modifying your bootply in the following manner: http://www.bootply.com/u6n2Y0S2gD#, but this doesn't create the effect that I want. What am I missing for xs screens?

Comment: @user3694391 I added what you need for hiding those divs - `hidden-xs`

Comment: Can you provide the link, please?

Comment: @user3694391 I have added the link to hiding.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly on bootply. However, on my actua website, the main is the longest column, so what happens in the sm screen, is that the right sidebar scrolls down to the left column but only where the main content ends. This is the opposite of what I wanted to achieve. The right sidebar needs to align directly beneath  the left sidebar, not align itself in the left sidebar column but leaving a huge blank space till the main ends to place itself in that column. Please check my edit above.

Comment: Just finished editing. The above edit shows how it looks now.